# Why does S-V or T-A couplings in Fermi weak interaction model produce electron oscillations?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, fermions, weak-interaction

In Fermi interaction model, vector bilinears were originally included in the interaction Lagrangian but since these couldn't explain nuclear spin changes other combinations were considered. However V-A couplings only survived. But before going to that in Greiner's book on gauge theory of weak interactions chapter 1 page 10, it is said S-V and T-A couplings cause electron oscillations and that it can be shown so.
What kind of oscillations are being talked about there and how can it be shown?